Getting Divine guidance for monumental decisions
When faced with monumental, potentially world history altering decisions like going to war, it would seem appropriate to get Divine approval, like was done using Urim V'Tumim, as opposed to only relying on a group of people's opinion (e.g. war cabinet).

For consulting Urim V'Tumim is it a requirement that the Beis Hamikdash be standing and most of the Jews are living in EY?  In other words, if Urim V'Tumim were found (or replicated?) now, can we (a Kohen) consult them?

If not, is there any other historically recorded or practiced or accepted way of making such decisions be Divinely approved? (For example, maybe assembling the leading Rabbis of the generation and taking a vote)


